# NameError in flask

Tags: python, flask

I 'm new to coding and I’m trying to do my first project. I want to make a movie search app but it constantly gives me errors. I get NameError: name 'movie' is not defined and UndefinedError: object has no atribute “plot”. How can i fix those errors? I should probably make a condition what to do if there is no plot atribute?

I suppose this is not the best way of doing things so I would appreciate any advice.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from imdb import IMDb

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    global movie, movie_two, movie_three
    if request.method == "POST":
        instance = IMDb()
        search = request.form.get("name")
        movie = instance.search_movie(search)

        movie_three = []

        for i in range(len(movie)):
            id_number = movie[i].movieID
            movie_two = instance.get_movie(id_number)
            movie_three.append(movie_two)

    return render_template("home.html", movie=movie, movie_two=movie_two, movie_three=movie_three)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content%}
<div align="center" >
    <h1>Something To Watch</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="search" action="{{url_for('home')}}" method="post">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Type here..." name="name" >
            <button type="submit" value="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


{% for m in movie_three %}
<div class="row">
    <div  align="center" class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src={{m["cover"]}} alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{m["title"]}}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{m["year"]}}</h6>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{m["kind"]}} - {{m["genres"]}}</h6>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{m["rating"]}}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{m["plot"][0]}}</p>


            <a href=# class="card-link">Go to IMDb</a>
            <a href="{{url_for('home')}}" class="card-link">Homepage</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 {%endfor%}

{% endblock %}
```

error:

```
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\korisnik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\app.py", line 36, in home
return render_template("home.html", movie=movie, movie_two=movie_two, movie_three=movie_three)
NameError: name 'movie' is not defined
```

Comment: If the request method is not POST, then all of the returned parameters are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because all your variables are defined inside the `if request.method == "POST":` block. Try setting another condition to handle the `GET` request and render just the `home.html` with it.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from imdb import IMDb

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    global movie, movie_two, movie_three
    if request.method == "POST":
        instance = IMDb()
        search = request.form.get("name")
        movie = instance.search_movie(search)

        movie_three = []

        for i in range(len(movie)):
            id_number = movie[i].movieID
            movie_two = instance.get_movie(id_number)
            movie_three.append(movie_two)

        return render_template("home.html", movie=movie, movie_two=movie_two, movie_three=movie_three)
    else:
        return render_template("home.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Now i get this TypeError:  quote_from_bytes() expected bytes 
for this line: ​movie = instance.search_movie(search)